# How to draw free and horizontal lines using mouse events and flags?

Tags: python, opencv, events, callback, flags

I try to build a code, in which I can draw lines above the image using OpenCV. In my code, I can draw lines freely, but I want draw horizontal lines, while I'm pressing the shift key. Actually, I didn't understand the exact logic of `flags` and the mouse `event`. Please let me know, how to fix my code.

```py
import cv2 
import numpy as np 

cropping = False

x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end = 0, 0, 0, 0

image = cv2.imread("C:/Users/USER-PC/Documents/python/image/sunflower.jpg")
oriImage = image.copy()

def draw_line(event, x,y, flags, param):
    global x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end, cropping 

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end = x,y,x,y
        cropping = True

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE and flags != cv2.EVENT_FLAG_SHIFTKEY:
        x_end, y_end = x,y
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE and flags == cv2.EVENT_FLAG_SHIFTKEY:
        x_end, y_end = x,y_start

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        x_end, y_end = x,y
        cropping = False
        cv2.line(image, (x_start, y_start),(x_end, y_end), (255,0,0),2)

cv2.namedWindow("image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("image", draw_line)

while (1):
    i = image.copy()

    if not cropping:

        cv2.imshow("image", image)
    elif cropping:


        cv2.line(i, (x_start, y_start),(x_end, y_end), (255,0,0),2)
        # cv2.rectangle(i, (x_start, y_start), (x_end, y_end), (255,0,0), 2)
        cv2.imshow("image", i)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF ==27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

Answer (score 1):

The `flags` consist of several bits, cf. the documentation on [mouse event flags](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#gaab4dc057947f70058c80626c9f1c25ce). For the case, you want to detect, you have `EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON` (value `1`) and the `EVENT_FLAG_SHIFTKEY` (value `16`) activated, so in that case `flags = 17`. Now, checking `flags == 17` might be one option, but it might be beneficial to specifically check, whether the `EVENT_FLAG_SHIFTKEY` bit is activated:

```py
shift_pressed = (flags & cv2.EVENT_FLAG_SHIFTKEY) > 0
```

This will return `True`, if the `EVENT_FLAG_SHIFTKEY` is activated, `False` otherwise.

Your `draw_line` method then could be modified in the following way:

```py
def draw_line(event, x,y, flags, param):
    global x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end, cropping

    shift_pressed = (flags & cv2.EVENT_FLAG_SHIFTKEY) > 0

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end = x, y, x, y
        cropping = True

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE and shift_pressed:
        x_end, y_end = x, y_start

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        x_end, y_end = x, y

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        x_end, y_end = x, y
        cropping = False
        cv2.line(image, (x_start, y_start), (x_end, y_end), (255, 0, 0), 2)
```

From my understanding of your question, this does, what you want to achieve.

Hope that helps!